# What is purpose of the property "private" in package.json?

Tags: node.js, package.json

I'm learning node.js and express, I am wondering what is the property "private" in ./package.json file used for?

Answer (score 341, accepted):

From the [NPM docs on `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#private):

> `private`
>
> If you set `"private": true` in your package.json, then npm will refuse to publish it.
>
> This is a way to prevent accidental publication of private repositories.

Comment: it is possible to configure it by default, in the global configuration "private": true.

Comment: @Gdaimon - how exactly do you set this default? In $HOME/.npmrc? `private=true` does not seem to work, `"private": true` doesn't either.

Comment: @Gdaimon - you can also use cli to do that, `npm config set init-private true`

Comment: What does it mean `npm publishing a package'??

Comment: @Soerendip for example, when you publish a library to the npmjs registry. published packages could be installed as a dependency via npm itself.
it is a common way to make a package available to public.
by the way it is possible to install packages using other methods like direct GitHub link or publishing into private package repositories.