# NPM - How to fix "No readme data"

Tags: npm

I have a simple package.json:

```
{
  "name": "camapaign",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.15",
    "npm": "1.3.5"
  },
  "repository": { 
    "type": "svn",
    "url": ""
  }
}
```

When I execute "npm install" i get the following warning which I would like to fix:

```
"npm WARN package.json camapaign@0.0.1 No readme data."
```

I have tried adding "README.md" & "readme.txt" to the same dir as the package but with no joy.  What am I missing?

Comment: An answer from NPM support that may be relevant for some: "It was just a delay in the website's cache needing to catch up to the publish."

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Simply adding a `README.md` file will not fix it, you should write something inside it; at least the project title and a brief description is good for people! But for NPM, one byte may be enough...
Doing so should stop showing the warnings.

Also, when you read that warning, ensure that the problem is not related to a 3rd party package.

Comment: I have this issue and I do have a non-empty README file... :/

Comment: Is it `README`, `README.markdown` or what? I'm afraid to say that only works with `README.md`... try it!

Comment: I too have a `README.md` file with a whole bunch of stuff in it in the same directory as my `package.json`, and still get this (in relation to karma-coffee-preprocessor)

Comment: Yup, same as @Conan. `README.md` file, populated, still getting the error.

Comment: @NathanHornby be sure that the problem isn't related to a 3rd party package.

Comment: @gustavohenke How silly of me, you're right - the warning was for a package, not my app

Comment: @NathanHornby as it was useful for you, I added it in the answer :)

Comment: +1 I came here because I got `npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<path>/package.json'` `npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<path>/package.json'` followed by several `npm WARN <path>` errors. Your comment "ensure that the problem is not related to a 3rd party package" helped me plus this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json - thanks!

Answer (score 176):

Just set as private ;)

```
{
  "name": "camapaign",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.15",
    "npm": "1.3.5"
  },
  "repository": { 
    "type": "svn",
    "url": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the property `private` tells npm that this is not a project intended to be available on the npm repository. You can see that someone already asked what's that property used for http://stackoverflow.com/a/7314961/1128216

Comment: If you set "private": true in your package.json, then npm will refuse to publish it. ref: `https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html`

Comment: Actually, in newer versions of NPM, it doesn't matter if the package is private or not. You must have a `README.md` file. @gustavohenke answer suits better every version.

Comment: This works okay if you are just using it to generate some output code and don't really need a full source package.

Comment: I would word this answer something like - Of course, the only reason not to have a `README.md` file is that your project is private. So either write a proper `README.md` **or** set the private flag.

Answer (score 10):

Adding a README.md to your project root is the answer, but I've noticed that it takes a short while for NPM to pick up on this. Maybe a few minutes?

Comment: It's true that after you publish it takes a moment to update NPM's listings. Here's a response from NPM's support: "It was just a delay in the website's cache needing to catch up to the publish."

Answer (score 1):

Add to package.json `"readme": "README.md"`

Comment: adding this property results in the *text* "README.md" displaying on the detail page on npmjs.com. Evidently, it is for raw markdown and not a filename.

Comment: It does however remove the npm warning - just not in the way this answer implies.

Comment: @code_monk so we could write something like "see [README.md](https://github.com/aloisdg/attrithub/blob/master/README.md)"

Comment: you could, but AFAIK simply adding a README.md at the root of your repo will fix this warning; which is a Good Idea, and will help your users understand how your software works

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Apr 2017, just setting below in package.json, still works fine:

```
"private": true
```

this means its your private repository

even, with latest npm, it works fine:

```
npm update -g npm
> 3.10.8
```

Answer (score 0):

#### my solution

- `npm show`
- `npm dist-tag add`

---

#### 1.use `npm show` check the remote website deploy info.

eg.should like this:

```
SOME_PACKAGEs@0.3.60-beta | Proprietary | deps: 14 | versions: 289
<span style="color:red;">最新日志倒序在这里增加，注明作者+日期+功能</span>

dist
.tarball: https://registry.npmjs.org/xxx/-/xxx-0.3.60-beta.tgz
.shasum: 021e30640a62f13905b1e2b7a4facd169df46a1d
.integrity: sha512-9N4pUwwoYGNek34fCCCjURuQdx1K5VBlCWl4t1sy8wi3xul/N/TiDvjmUBF24t2Dg2fX6cFM9on+tftnVaEr7A==
.unpackedSize: 114.5 kB

dependencies:
@hanyk/rc-viewer: ^0.0.3        crypto-js: ^3.1.9-1             moment: ^2.25.3                 react-dom: ^16.12.0             uuid: ^3.3.3                    
axios: ^0.19.0                  dirty-json-ie11: ^0.0.2         query-string: ^6.9.0            react-quill: ^1.3.3             yqquill-image-drop-module: ^0.0 
cookie-universal: ^2.0.16       md5: ^2.2.1                     quill-delta-to-html: ^0.11.0    react-resizable: ^1.10.1        

maintainers:
- jyjin <jyjin@qq.com>
- jyjin1 <jyjin1@163.com>
- jyjin2 <jyjin2@163.com>

dist-tags:
beta: 0.3.61-beta    latest: 0.3.53-beta  

published 26 minutes ago by jyjin1 <jyjin1@163.com>
```

#### 2.`npm dist-tag add [PACKAGE_NAME]@[VERSION]`

and then update lasest `0.3.53-beta` to `0.3.61-beta`

`npm dist-tag add SOME_PACKAGE@0.3.61-beta`

#### 3.`npm show` check agin

same to step 1

go back to your npm package site, all have refreshed!

---

Wish to helps, thanks~

[One Chinese Teach]希望对您有帮助，谢谢~