# npm command prompt Installing

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm new to nodejs, I tried typing npm install and it brought this error log:

> npm warn saveerror ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   open C:\users\kiddy\package.json
>   npm WARN kiddy no description 
>   npm WARN kiddy no repository field
>   Npm WARN kiddy no README data

How do I overcome above error?

Answer (score 0):

Before installing any packages with the npm install command, you have to have a package.json. Use this in the folder

```
npm init
```

Now, you can install packages.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to NodeJS. Hope this little issue hasn't deterred you, and hopefully by now you have overcome this challenge and moved on your NodeJS journey. But in spirit of sharing knowledge, here is what had happened.

As your `npm install` script indicated, you have not provided `description` and `repository` fields, and [you don't have a `README.md` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18086706/1834562).

The easiest way to create a new `package.json` is to run the [`npm init command`](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file#creating-a-default-packagejson-file).

> npm init --yes

Here is a sample package.json file to get you started. Best of luck!!

```
  {
    "name": "my_package",
    "description": "Awesome NodeJS project.",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package.git"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
      "url": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package"
  }
```