# “No readme data” with package.json not in root folder

Tags: npm, package.json

I have a directory structure with a `Build` and a `Source` Folder.
Alls things Grunt, npm, bower and composer live in the `Build` Folder, All sources live in the `Source` Folder and all Things Project (*i.e. `README.md`*) live in the root of the project.

```
- myProject
   + Build
      Gruntfile.js
      bower.json
      package.json
      ...
   + Source
      + vendor
      + src
      ...
   README.md
   composer.json
```

So now if i run `npm install` in the build Folder, npm claims my Project is missing a README, which is not true.
Also i am simply using the package.json to install npm dependencies for grunt. My project is not a npm project.

Can i somehow tell npm that it is not run in the root of the project?
Or can i tell npm that my project is not a npm project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

- If you have no intention to publish this package to npm then you can set private to true as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314849/what-is-purpose-of-the-property-private-in-package-json/7314961#7314961)
- You can set the location of readme with the readme property as seen below:

  ```
  {
     "name": "app_name",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "author": "your name here",
     "description": "A descriptive description",
     "license": "MIT",
     "readme": "../README.md"
  }
  ```

As far as I can tell, there's no validation on the readme property but it will squelch the warning.