# What should I put in the license field of package.json if my code is only for use by the company I work for?

Tags: node.js, package.json, spdx

NPM 2.11.3

I'm building a library in Node. This library is only for use by the company I am currently working for. I think this means that the license is "None". But when I `npm init` it wants me to use an SPDX License. "None" or "Unlicensed" are not valid options.

`npm WARN package.json data_monitoring_api@0.1.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression`

There is some discussion around this on the NPM GitHub issue tracker but I can't find anything that definitively answers this. Perhaps NPM doesn't support this concept, but that seems odd.

What should I put for this field in this case? I'd like to get rid of the npm warnings related to this.

While the docs say that UNLICENSED is valid, it still gives a warning:

```
$ cat package.json | grep licen
  "license": "UNLICENSED",

$ npm install 
npm WARN package.json data_monitoring_api@0.1.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
```

Comment: I think this is your answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/285885/which-spdx-license-is-equivalent-to-all-rights-reserved

Comment: Looks like it @SimonGroenewolt, want to put that in as an answer?

Comment: NPM issue discussing this topic: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8918#issuecomment-138059254

Comment: This is now irrelevant.  NPM gave up on trying to force your license and now allows `SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.txt`, which you set as `Copyright 20xx by xxx.  All rights reserved.  No license granted.'

Comment: Charles hasn't that always been an option?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Use `UNLICENSED` per [the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json):

> Finally, if you do not wish to grant others the right to use a private or unpublished package under any terms:

```
{
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

<sub>This is not to be confused with the license that was confusingly called ["The Unlicense"](https://spdx.org/licenses/Unlicense.html).</sub>

Answer (score 96):

> at the time of writing UNLICENSED (see the code sample in the
> question) was not an option please see [jcollum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35069236/181569)

Adding `private` to `package.json` will help:

```
"private": true
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the license, you may want to publish a copyrighted module to your own registry:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314849/what-is-purpose-of-the-property-private-in-package-json

"If you set "private": true in your package.json, then npm will refuse to publish it.

    This is a way to prevent accidental publication of private repositories."

Comment: at the time of writing UNLICENSED - (see the code sample in the question) was not an option please see [jcollumns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35069236/181569)

Comment: This used to be the technically correct answer, because the node team does not seem to understand that sometimes you need to "publish" something that is not free software. With the addition of UNLICENSED this is no longer correct.

Comment: This post does not answer the question. I edited the post to make it answer the question and to explain what `private` actually does (it has nothing to do with licensing), but unfortunately my edit got rolled back.

Comment: doesnt help in node 14

Comment: and good idea - to remove "license": "UNLICENSED"

Comment: I see a lot of people saying this doesn't help at all, but it actually removed the error message for me. This is the only thing I changed. Using yarn 1.22.19 and node 16.17

Answer (score 13):

On the second column of the table found on this link, https://spdx.org/licenses/, you can see all the different SPDX format to used in your `package.json`.

The name of the column is `Identifier` just in case. Thanks and hope it helps.

Comment: This is right, but please note this in the link "The SPDX License List is a list of commonly found licenses and exceptions used in free and open source and other collaborative software or documentation. ". That means the SPDX doesn't apply to a company copyrighted license.

Comment: Somehow I get a warning for `"license": "CC-PDDC"`

Answer (score 4):

For me whatever license I put in the code did not work. But then I figured out, that there is a invalid package.json in the parent directory. After removing it, this solved all the issues.

Comment: It's very odd that npm would be reading a package.json in the parent directory at all. Something seems broken here.

Comment: I've actually just experienced the same issue. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't make sense, but I just ran into the same thing. I had a stray package.json three levels up and I was getting warnings about it. Delete that and the warnings went away.

Comment: I had the same issue and struggled with it for a while. Weird indeed.

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks. Spent hours researching what to put in the field, and the problem was in a parent folder...