# What's the "private" flag yarn init?

Tags: yarnpkg

When I run `yarn init` one of the questions is `question private`. I searched everywhere but couldn't find an explaination for that. What does it mean `private` in this context?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`yarn init` is meant to assist you in the process of creating a `package.json` for a new project.

`private` means adding a `private: true` field in the autogenerated `package.json`, which will instruct `npm` to [refuse publishing the package to the public NPM registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314849/what-is-purpose-of-the-property-private-in-package-json) on `npm publish`.