# angular material is not recognized in firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

While serving in local host is working properly but when I deploy in the firebase hosting, angular materials is not recognized.
displaying as plain html page

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/app name",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The styles of angular material were not displayed correctly when I wanted to deploy my app in firebase, but the animations worked. So I found this:
[What is purpose of the property "private" in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314849/what-is-purpose-of-the-property-private-in-package-json)

After I set "private: true" to "false" my styles were correctly displayed.